# Gestures on a rzComboBox

Tags: delphi

I am working on an application to be used on a windows tablet.

I have been playing around with the gesture manager and i have linked it to my rzComboBox. On the onGesture event of the combo box i have:

```
if EventInfo.GestureID = sgiDown then
  ShowMessage('CB Down')
else if EventInfo.GestureID = sgiUp then
  ShowMessage('CB Up');
```

The problem i am having is it only seems to hit the ShowMessages whenever i make a gesture on the closed combobox and not when i make a gesture on the dropped down part of the combo box.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Isn't the drop-down list actually a separate control, so maybe you need to find a way of register that with the Gesture Manager?

Comment: The dropped down list control is probably not capable of gestures as it also tracks the mouse itself. You might as well experience similar problems with a plain TListBox.